# Red lines under ViewBag and HTML.TextboxFor helpers in Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 that comes with MVC4, and opened a project done in MVC3.

On my views, all references to:

```
ViewBag.<Property>
```

Showed the red waved lines, saying "dynamic library missing", and

```
HTML.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)
HTML.HiddenFor(m => m.Property)
etc...
```

Showed error "arguments cannot be inferred from usage".

I found the answered in other no-related thread, so I'm opening this question here to help others, as I didn't find it in Google looking for the main topic. Below the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the web.config file :

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

change it to:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Thanks to [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102410/jim) that posted a tiny comment on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969321/the-type-arguments-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage-try-specifying-the-type-ar)

Comment: I have <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"> but still error

Answer (score 1):

I tried troubleshooting this similar issue for hours.  Red lines under all @Html helpers.  Everything I read on SOF and other sites would not work.  The web app would compile and run fine.

The way I fixed my issue was by uploading all my code to my Visual Studio Online environment.  Delete the project folder/solution on my local machine. Close Visual Studio.  Open Visual Studio.  Connect to team explorer and do a get latest from the source control explorer.

Finally, go to File > Open > Project within VS and open the project .sln file.

All the red lines and visual studio cache/temp files are cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

In your Web.Config file make sure that the compilation target framework matches the 
 httpRuntime target framework version e.g.:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I have all this in my web.config file and it doesn't help. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
I was missing a closing bracket in a pretty complex Razor page with lots of "while" and "if" and code brackets. Simple closing bracket, pulled out most of my hair. Take care.