# Using Dynamic.Linq, how to return query to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic

```
var query =     this.testFormsDataSet.Consignment.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(groupBy, "it")
.Select(selectBy);
```

With that query is all OK.

But right now I don't understand how to save query to DataTable. I tried to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx .

```
DataTable res = CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods.CopyToDataTable(query);
```

or

```
DataTable res = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

But `CopyToDataTable` still doesn't work.

Please help!!

Comment: It says: "The type arguments for method '___' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: You could try adding a `Cast<DataRow>()` before the `CopyToDataTable()`, but remember that the result of the `Select` **must** be a `DataRow` (because `CopyToDataTable` works only on `DataRow`s)

Comment: What .net framework?

Comment: Does `query.ToList()` work at all? try that first.

Comment: @GertArnold query.ToList() does not work...

Comment: @xanatos I tried use 'Cast<DataRow>()' but in that class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx  I get  an Error system.invalidcastexception Failed to cast object of type "DynamicClass2" to "System.Data.DataRow".

Comment: @MaciejLos .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: It should works as well. I'd suggest to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969321/the-type-arguments-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage-try-specifying-the-type-ar - answer by Jim.

Comment: More about error causes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxfhx4sy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Kavrat The failing `ToList()` is your problem. Dynamic LINQ is meant to work on `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Convert IEnumerable to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable)

```
public static class DynamicLinqDataTableHelpers
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IQueryable items)
    {
        Type type = items.ElementType;

        // Create the result table, and gather all properties of a type        
        DataTable table = new DataTable(type.Name);

        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Add the properties as columns to the datatable
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

            // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type 
            if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType);
            }

            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
        }

        // Add the property values as rows to the datatable
        foreach (object item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];

            if (item != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
            }

            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

and then

```
DataTable res = query.ToDataTable();
```

The main difference is that instead of "extracting" the type T through generics, I use the `ElementType` property of the `IQueryable`

Now... you seems to use a strange variation of Dynamic LINQ that works on `IEnumerable`... I've adapted the `ToDataTable`:

```
public static class DynamicLinqDataTableHelpers
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable items)
    {
        // Create the result table, and gather all properties of a type        
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        PropertyInfo[] props = null;

        // Add the property values as rows to the datatable
        foreach (object item in items)
        {
            if (props == null && item != null)
            {
                Type type = item.GetType();
                props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                // Add the properties as columns to the datatable
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                {
                    Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

                    // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type 
                    if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    {
                        propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType);
                    }

                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
                }
            }

            // When the column headers are defined, all the rows have
            // their number of columns "fixed" to the right number
            var values = new object[props != null ? props.Length : 0];

            if (item != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
            }

            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. "Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable' "
Error 2 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable' and the best extension method overload 'MyForm.DynamicLinqDataTableHelpers.ToDataTable(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Kavrat There is something strange in your query: `this.testFormsDataSet.Consignment.AsEnumerable().GroupBy`, but I know that Dynamic LINQ doesn't work on `AsEnumerable()`. Try removing the `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @Kavrat Ok... Try telling me the types of `this.testFormsDataSet` and `this.testFormsDataSet.Consignment`. If you do a `var xx = this.testFormsDataSet` and move the mouse on `var` you should be able to see it. Do the same for `Consignment`

Comment: 'this.testFormsDataSet.Consignment' - Represents the strongly named clas DataTable, 'this.TestFormsDataSet' - Represents strongly typed in-memory cache od data.

Comment: @Kavrat and you told that `this.testFormsDataSet.Consignment.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(groupBy, "it").Select(selectBy)` will compile?

Comment: Yes. I displayed result like that: 'foreach (var item in query) {MessageBox.Show(item.ToString()); }' And result was as I expexted

Comment: @What type does it have `query`?

Comment: 'Interface System.Collections.IEnumerable. Exposes the enumerator , which supports a simple iteration over non-generoc collection'

Comment: @Kavrat The `GroupBy` and the `Select`, if you do `Go To Definition` on them, do you have them in a source file or are they defined in a referenced assembly? Because they are "non-standard". I've created a version of `ToDataTable` that should work for you.

Comment: GroupBy and Select are from System.Linq.Dynamic                    '#region Assembly System.Linq.Dynamic.dll, v1.0.3.0
// D:\C#\MyForm\packages\System.Linq.Dynamic.1.0.4\lib\net40\System.Linq.Dynamic.dll
#endregion', 'public static class DynamicQueryable'

Comment: @Kavrat No, simply there are multiple implementation around... probably 3 or 4. If it does what you need, then it is the right one :)