# Issues with concatenating after Array.Select in C#

Tags: c#, function, types, typeerror

I'm working on the following code for a uni project:

```
public Order[] collapse()
{
    return ConcatArrays(Rondes.Select(rs => rs.collapse()));
}

public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(T[][] list)
{
    var result = new T[list.Sum(a => a.Length)];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
    {
        list[x].CopyTo(result, offset);
        offset += list[x].Length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here `rs` is of a custom type `Ronde`, and `rs.collapse()` returns `Order[]`. The goal of the first function is to compute `rs.collapse()` for every `rs`, and concatenate these arrays. How do I resolve the following error:

```
The type arguments for method ConcatArrays<T>(T[][]) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I tried to follow the reccomendation by changing all `T`'s to `Order`, but that did not change the error message. Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have now changed the first function to:

```
public Order[] collapse()
    {
        if (Rondes == null) { return new Order[0]; }
        return OrderLijsten.ConcatArrays<Order>(Rondes.Select(rs => rs.collapse()));
    }
```

but now i get this error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Grote_Opdracht.Classes.Order[]>' to 'Grote_Opdracht.Classes.Order[][]'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969321/the-type-arguments-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage-try-specifying-the-type-ar)

Comment: @Luuk I don't really understand this question, so no sadly, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message gives you a pretty clear explanation: Your `Select` call returns an `IEnumerable` but this ConcatArrays implementation expects an *array* (of arrays).

You could either make the method use `IEnumerable` (but then you would enumerate multiple times), or call `ToArray` to make an array. In this case, I would prefer a combination, and also use `ToList` instead, which should be the most performant option:

```
public Order[] Collapse()
{
    // make sure to iterate only once
    var arrays = Rondes.Select(rs => rs.collapse()).ToList();
    return ConcatArrays(arrays);
}

// use IEnumerable to be more flexible
public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(IEnumerable<T[]> arrays)
{
    var result = new T[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (var a in arrays)
    {
        a.CopyTo(result, offset);
        offset += a.Length;
    }
    return result;
}
```